# How to access a model's relation within a form collection in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

FollowedTopic belongs to a Topic, and I'd like to be able to output the parents "topic.title" in place of the last ":id" symbol.

```
<%= f.collection_select(:followedtopic_id, FollowedTopic.all, :id, :id) %>
```

I've been struggling for hours to figure this out, is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= f.select :followedtopic_id, FollowedTopic.includes(:topic).all.map{|ft| [ft.topic.title, ft.id] } %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the possible solution, but this gives me an error "undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: Do all `FollowedTopic`s have a `Topic`? Is it possible that at least one FollowedTopic does not have a topic (maybe it was deleted)?

Comment: Ah, yes! I believe that is the case actually, I will sort this out, and try again. Cheers